# Undefined reference to class method which inherits from template which inherits from QAbstractItemModel

Tags: c++, qt, templates, inheritance

I am having some difficulty getting my derived classes to function with a project I am working on.

The project is using QT.  I am using Model-View architecture, and the project has a number of models, which more or less model different business objects which share a lot of logic.

At the moment, each model inherits from QAbstractTableModel and functions satisfactorily.  The issue is that there is some duplication between these models, and I would strongly prefer not to repeat code multiple times.

Therefore, I have created a generic base class, which inherits from QAbstractTableModel which implements the common functionality (adding rows to databases, executing common business logic, retrieving header data).  The models the views use inherit from this derived class, and implement table specific functionality (mainly getting and setting data from objects which represent the data).  So the generic base class provides part of the functionality, and the specific instances of the model complete it.

So QAbstractTableModel -> QualityItemModel -> (the various models the views will use).

QualityItemModel I have made a template, as some shared code must work with different types.

The issue is I am getting the following error after linking, when trying to call these methods.

```
/home/user/program/project/UI/complaintsui.cpp:136: undefined reference to `ComplaintsModel::clear()'
moc_complaintsmodel.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV15ComplaintsModel[_ZTV15ComplaintsModel]+0x70): undefined reference to `ComplaintsModel::index(int, int, QModelIndex const&) const'
moc_complaintsmodel.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV15ComplaintsModel[_ZTV15ComplaintsModel]+0x88): undefined reference to `ComplaintsModel::rowCount(QModelIndex const&) const'
moc_complaintsmodel.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV15ComplaintsModel[_ZTV15ComplaintsModel]+0x90): undefined reference to `ComplaintsModel::columnCount(QModelIndex const&) const'
moc_complaintsmodel.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV15ComplaintsModel[_ZTV15ComplaintsModel]+0xb0): undefined reference to `ComplaintsModel::headerData(int, Qt::Orientation, int) const'
moc_complaintsmodel.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV15ComplaintsModel[_ZTV15ComplaintsModel]+0x140): undefined reference to `ComplaintsModel::flags(QModelIndex const&) const'
```

Complaints model inherits from the template, which inherits from QAbstractTableModel.  Oddly, other methods which I have added don't have this error.  The template is implemented in the header file, so the issue isn't template code in a .cpp file.

Code as follows.  I have omitted the code in the implementation for brevity.

QualityItemModel.h

```
#ifndef QUALITYITEMMODEL_H
#define QUALITYITEMMODEL_H
#include <QVector>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>

template <typename T>
class QualityItemModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{

public:
   explicit QualityItemModel(QObject *parent = 0);


  QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;
  void remove(int row);
  int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
  Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;
  QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const;
  int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
  void add(T c);
  void clear();
  bool submit();
  void junk();


protected:
  QVector<T> modelItemList;
  int currentRow;
  int row;

  typename QVector<T>::const_iterator modelItemListItr;
  typename QVector<T>::const_iterator begin() const { return modelItemList.begin(); }
  typename QVector<T>::const_iterator end() const { return modelItemList.end(); }

};

template <typename T>
QualityItemModel<T>::QualityItemModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
}

template <typename T>
QVariant QualityItemModel<T>::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{

}

template <typename T>
void QualityItemModel<T>::remove(int row)
{


}


template <typename T>
int QualityItemModel<T>::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{

}


template <typename T>
Qt::ItemFlags QualityItemModel<T>::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{

}


template <typename T>
QModelIndex QualityItemModel<T>::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{

}

template <typename T>
int QualityItemModel<T>::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{

}

template <typename T>
void QualityItemModel<T>::add(T c)
{

}

template <typename T>
void QualityItemModel<T>::clear()
{

}

template <typename T>
bool QualityItemModel<T>::submit()
{


}

template <typename T>
void QualityItemModel<T>::junk() {qDebug() << "Junk";}



#endif // QUALITYITEMMODEL_H
```

The code to inherit this template is

ComplaintsModel.h

```
class ComplaintsModel : public QualityItemModel<Complaint>
```

with constructor

```
ComplaintsModel::ComplaintsModel(QObject *parent) :  QualityItemModel(parent)
{

}
```

ComplaintsModel then implements the 'data' and 'setdata' methods.

This is used later in the following fashion

```
ComplaintsModel *model = new ComplaintsModel(this);
model->clear() // Linker error
model->junk()  // No linker error
```

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that QAbstractTableModel is an abstract class, but I'm not quite sure how to resolve this issue.

The alternative is that I template only helper functions, rather than the entire class.

Comment: I think you should `inline` your definitions.

Comment: I discovered that I left the method definitions in the derived class.  Taking them out of the final derived class solved this issue. I might delete this question.